# how to run commands for nginx docker image?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to run a command on the `nginx:latest` container from my `docker-compose.yml`
I thought it would be practical to create a dummy certificate right at startup, but no matter what i try to run at entrypoint, the NGINX container just exits upon docker-compose up.

This is just a test script, and not used in production

```yaml
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: 'no'
    environment:
      keysize: 4096
      email: x@x.com
      domains: > 
        (
        x.com,
        www.x.com
        )
    entrypoint: >
      - apk update && apk add bash
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get clean
      - |
        curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/_internal/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf" &&
        curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem" &&
        for domain in ${domains[@]}; do
          openssl req \
          -x509 \
          -nodes \
          -newkey rsa:$keysize \
          -days 1 \
          -keyout "/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/privkey.pem" \
          -out "./etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/fullchain.pem" \
          -subj "/CN=localhost"
        done
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:   
      - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt
```